# remove one cell from a range

Tags: excel, vba

I want to delete first cell of H column of a table set as rng8 and put the new object in rng9. The cell I want to exclude is the header of the column. I use below commands but they don't work

```
Set rng8 = Sheets(firstsheetname).Range("H:H") 

Set rng9 = rng8.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng8.Rows.Count - 1, rng8.Columns.Count)
```

Comment: You will have to resize then offset as otherwise you are trying to go down 1 from the last row in the sheet.

Comment: What is the point, would you really want the whole column H but the first row? Or do you want to get the last used row in column H? This way you end up with a huge range :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are experiencing an error because when you try to offset the whole column by one row down, there is no further row below (since you have selected the whole column).
Based **solely** on your question and code, this works:

```
Set rng8 = Sheets(firstsheetname).Range("H:H") 
Set rng9 = rng8.Cells(1,1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(rng8.Rows.Count - 1, rng8.Columns.Count)
```

In fact, if you actually do not need `rng8` then you can set rng9 thus:

```
With Sheets(firstsheetname)
    Set rng9 = .Range("H2:H", & .Rows.Count)
End With
```

However, as someone commented, if you are interested only in setting up to the **last used row** of Column H, then use this:

```
With Sheets(firstsheetname)
    Set rng9 = .Range("H2", .Range("H" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
End With
```